# Android Layout not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having an issue with my layout, here is my code for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/Scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/Table"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/BookingStatus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/BookingBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/statusbarcomplete"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BookingBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/Red"
            android:text="Place My Booking"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how it looks on a small device:
[image: Small Device]

Here is how it looks on a large device 
[image: Big Device]

Now as you can see the issue is with the small device, the button and the image seem to "float" over the top of the layout whereas I want them on the buttom of the layout at all times. Therefor the user will need to scroll on a small device BUT the image and the button at the bottom will ALWAYS be at the bottom and ALWAYS visible! The scrollview will take up the rest of the screen so that the user can see the information.

You can view the full code for the xml file [here](http://pastebin.com/aGvF4PhW). I deleted all of the tablerows to keep this thread tidy and because the code was over 300 lines

Comment: You can assign the layout-height value for the scroll view...

Comment: you need to follow http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html and what i did in my case i made a specific layout-mdpi,layout-xhdpi, and so on specific directories inside res and at run time that layout would be displayed according to the size of the screen NOTE * only add those layout which get disturbed on screen dpi change to these directories

Comment: layout-height would never work, it would only work for a specific resolution surely?

Comment: Spry - Already have :) It doesnt explain how to have something at the bottom of the screen the whole time with a scrollable for the rest of the screen

Comment: @apmartin1991 i would suggest u to use Listview instead of such complex table layout and there are many issues in your codes

Comment: What issues are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/Scroll"
            android:layout_above="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/Table"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/BookingStatus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/BookingBtn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BookingBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@color/Red"
            android:text="Place My Booking"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this. Just place the scrollview above the relative layout containing image and button.

Comment: Seems to have done the trick, let me test on both a small and a large device and I shall get back to you, will mark as correct if it works.

Comment: @apmartin1991 This answer will work as long as your bottom content fits inside that 10dp padding.

Comment: The scrollview is above the bottom content. It doesnt matter if your content is above 10dp.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this..
place this in last RelativeLayout.

android:layout_gravity="bottom"